# Intellj reformat ignores the eslint-diable comment, how to fix it?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I hit Intellj reformat. The reformat will do the format on it's own way and ignore the eslint comment.
For example, I have the below code in my project.
I hope intellj can skip the reformat for the code inside the  **    /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */** block.

But it won't work with prettier plugin.

How could I fix this inside intellj?

```
root: $template(
    /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
    '<div>' +
        '<div class="checkbox-group" />' +
    '</div>'
    /* eslint-enable prettier/prettier */
)
```

After applying reformat (this is not what i need)

```
root: $template(
    /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

    '<div>' + '<div class="checkbox-group" />' + '</div>'

    /* eslint-enable prettier/prettier */
)
```

Comment: `eslint-disable` comments just disable ESLint warnings, they have nothing to do with IDEA formatter. Either use **Reformat with Prettier** (or `eslint --fix`) to format your code, or use IDE own way to skip certain lines on reformatting, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/settings-code-style.html#formatter-control